# How to speed up SQL Query with 30+ joins

Tags: sql, join, query-optimization, inner-join

I've been tasked with selecting a lot of information from an existing table, and pulling out a LOT of information per row.  I am doing this through a 3rd party piece of software, so I cannot edit the table, columns, or data, I can only SELECT to view it.

Because this is a 3rd party piece of software, I am very limited with what I can do, as this information is all saved into 2 tables that (For some reason) only has 60 columns accessible to them both combined

Due to this, I am having to select employee information that has been inserted across two columns, so I JOIN these together where the name/unique val is the same, this works fine.

Next I have to SELECT timing information, workplace information, previous employment details, etc etc, and all of these pieces of information are on their own rows, with overlapping column names of course! so i'm joining WHERE certain fields are the same etc.

Also, because this is a 3rd party piece of software and I cannot DELETE entries, i am having to select the most recent version of each row, as when information is updated, it just inserts a new row with that employee information, rather than deleting it (helpful).

So this is where I'm at, I'm joining two tables on itself 34 times to get all of these rows needed, now this works and produces the correct information every single time, the issue in this case is performance, depending on the Employee name, it can take from 60 seconds to 180 seconds to run (not ideal).

My question is, whats the best way to speed this up? (if there is a way), I have gone from full joining to inner joining, I have reorganised the WHERE clauses to get it to be most efficient, but it's still rather slow.

As mentioned before, I only have access to TWO tables with 60 columns across both, I cannot DELETE or Overwrite entries, nor can I create tables or shuffle data around, I'm effectively stuck doing it this way as far as I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
SELECT * 

      FROM table2 sm1
       
       INNER JOIN table2 sm2 ON sm1.col_40 = sm2.col_40
       INNER JOIN table1 im on sm1.unique_val = im.unique_val 
       INNER JOIN table1 im2 on sm2.unique_val = im2.unique_val 
        
       INNER JOIN table2 op ON sm1.col_25 = op.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op1 ON sm2.col_37 = op1.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op2 ON im2.we = op2.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op3 ON im2.dem_1 = op3.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op4 ON im2.dem_3 = op4.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op5 ON im2.dem_5 = op5.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op6 ON im2.dem_7 = op6.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op7 ON im2.dem_9 = op7.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op8 ON im2.mat_1 = op8.col_3 
       INNER JOIN table2 op9 ON im2.areas = op9.col_3 
        
       INNER join table1 opim1 on op.unique_val = opim1.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim2 on op1.unique_val = opim2.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim3 on op2.unique_val = opim3.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim4 on op3.unique_val = opim4.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim5 on op4.unique_val = opim5.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim6 on op5.unique_val = opim6.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim7 on op6.unique_val = opim7.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim8 on op7.unique_val = opim8.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim9 on op8.unique_val = opim9.unique_val 
       INNER join table1 opim10 on op9.unique_val = opim10.unique_val 


       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_40, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_40) 
       groupedSM ON groupedSM.col_40 = sm1.col_40 

       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped ON grouped.col_8 = op.col_8 
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped1 ON grouped1.col_8 = op1.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped2 ON grouped2.col_8 = op2.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped3 ON grouped3.col_8 = op3.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped4 ON grouped4.col_8 = op4.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped5 ON grouped5.col_8 = op5.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped6 ON grouped6.col_8 = op6.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped7 ON grouped7.col_8 = op7.col_8  
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped8 ON grouped8.col_8 = op8.col_8  
        
        
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col_8, MAX(time_added) AS MaxTime FROM table2 GROUP BY col_8) 
       grouped9 ON grouped9.col_8 = op9.col_8  


       WHERE sm1.col_3 = '*EmployeeName*' 
       AND sm2.col_3 = sm1.col_3 
       AND sm1.col_39 = sm2.col_39  
       and sm1.col_4 = 'Part1' 
       and sm2.col_4 = 'Part2' 
       and groupedSM.MaxTime = sm2.time_added 
       and im.type = im2.type

       AND opim1.ID = 188374 
       AND opim2.ID = 188374 
       AND opim3.ID = 188374 
       AND opim4.ID = 188374 
       AND opim5.ID = 188374 
       AND opim6.ID = 188374 
       AND opim7.ID = 188374 
       AND opim8.ID = 188374 
       AND opim9.ID = 188374 
       AND opim10.ID = 188374 
       
       AND grouped.MaxTime = op.time_added 
       AND grouped1.MaxTime = op1.time_added 
       AND grouped2.MaxTime = op2.time_added 
       AND grouped3.MaxTime = op3.time_added 
       AND grouped4.MaxTime = op4.time_added 
       AND grouped5.MaxTime = op5.time_added 
       AND grouped6.MaxTime = op6.time_added 
       AND grouped7.MaxTime = op7.time_added 
       AND grouped8.MaxTime = op8.time_added 
       AND grouped9.MaxTime = op9.time_added
```

Comment: I think you dont need 30+ joins at all. You should overthink your statement structure, because you can easily made it shorter and faster

Comment: Please add to your question the table structures some sample data and the result you expect to get from your sample data

Comment: What database make and version do you use? Can you add indexes to your tables? Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to give us more information.